# Concisely wording the sentence "compare X's Y to Z's Y"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, possessives, apostrophe

How would one go about concisely wording the sentence "compare X's Y to Z's Y." I've seen it done in a few ways:

1. "compare X's Y to Z's Y" (e.g. "compare Mary's lamb to Phillip's lamb")
2. "compare X's Y to Z's" (e.g. "compare Mary's lamb to Phillip's")
3. "compare X's and Y's Zs" (e.g. "compare Mary's and Phillip's lambs")

However, all three of these sound slightly incorrect to me.

Comment: Personally I can't see anything wrong with option one, it's clear and unambiguous. Option two is a little shorter because the second property is implied rather than stated, but it could be considered a bit more ambiguous since the hearers could find themselves waiting for Philip's property and mentally asking "Philip's what?". However it is a standard way to ask the question. Option 3 is often used but I find it a bit awkward and, perhaps a bit stilted and old fashioned. I don't think there is a more efficient way to ask it.

Comment: I tend to agree that 1 is the best option. However, it could be very tedious to write sentences like this where Y is a property that is described in several words, i.e. "compare Mary's unidentified flying spacecraft to Phillip's unidentified flying spacecraft." However, after considering your answer, it seems like it is just a balance.

Comment: I accept your point about possessions described by long phrases, in which case option 2 is probably the best. The worst thing to do is to say "Compare Mary and Philip's lambs' because "Mary and Philip's lambs" are lambs owned jointly by Mary and Philip. "Mary and Philip's children" are usually children whose parents are Mary and Philip.

Comment: *How would one go about **efficiently** wording the sentence* Could you expand upon what you mean by "efficiently"?

Comment: I've updated the question title to better express what I mean.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe...

Compare "X's" and "Z's" common trait.

Comment: It might help if you included a real world example.

Comment: Wouldn't the common trait just be Y? In which case, this only serves to bring us back to the initial problem.

Comment: The quotes are just weird. Compare "invertedPanda's" and "Craig Kirby's" sentences.

Comment: I thought the point was to attempt to put the problem into efficient English rather than a formula. Sorry if I got hooked on the wording re: "wording". I figured the OP was searching for a word like "trait" to replace the Ys. This being the case, "trait" fits quite nicely, but to be honest, I'm not sure it's even English (although it is in the Cambridge Dictionary.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trait

Comment: I used quotes because I was quoting someone. You used your's to be condescending. But it's all good.

Comment: This answer doesn’t address the question, which is about how to structure an unwieldy sentence.